# datatables jquery - alternate colors for the rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used datatables jquery in my application. When I used datatables jquery to set alternate colors for my rows, I faced a issue. That is, in a table 2nd,3rd,4th,5th n 6th row are all displayed in same color and after that colors are displayed alternately. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

My code in jquery.datatables.css :

```
table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color:  red; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: green;  }
```

I have attached the screenshot of the table.

[image]

When I checked, every row is having either class="even" or class="odd" but the 2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th rows are having class="odd even". I dont know why it is like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer :

```
table.dataTable tr{ background-color:  red; }
table.dataTable tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color: green;  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `:odd` and `:even` pseudo selecters

```
table.dataTable tr:odd { background-color:  red; }
table.dataTable tr:even { background-color: green;}
```

Comment: OP is using classes like `odd` and `even`, And I suggest the `css pseudos`

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry didn't saw that! +1

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have used

```
#tableid >  thead >tr  {background: #0F0}   /* to color thead*/


table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color:  red; }   /* tr. not tr: */
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: green;}
```

as a css rule and it works. Hope the same works for your application .

Comment: I noticed the same, DataTable add the class "odd" or "even" with all <tr>

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work .
add those lines in datatable css file

```
table.dataTable >tbody td {
    text-align: center;
    background: #99BCDB;
}

table.dataTable > tbody tr.odd td { 
    background: #EBF2F8
;
}
```